# Application Resident size and Dirty size in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

When my application starts, its resident size will be 114MB and Dirty size will be about 45MB. As I use the app, Resident and Dirty size keeps on increasing to a max extent of 170MB and 100MB respectively. While saving, Resident and dirty size increases to 300MB and 224MB respectively. Actually, there are about 324 images of which 108 images are of 55x72 resolution, 108 are of 562x562 resolution and rest 108 are of 2244x2244 images.

To display all the images in Scrollview, I am using thumbnails images of size 55x72. To play around with the images I use Proxy images of size 562x562 and while saving I use high resolution images of size 2244x2244.

I release all thumbnails and proxy images before saving so as to reduce the memory and also release all the objects which are of no use during saving. I am splitting the image into 4 parts and then merge them into a single image so as to reduce the memory consumption.

I am using [UIImage imageWithContentsOfTheFile] method and I have used autorelease pools to drain right after image to set to ImageView. memory leaks are not there in the program.

Will the application crash at any point if the app uses about 300MB resident and 224MB of Dirty size?

Comment: I'm confused.. but i can guess resident means size on disk and dirty means size on ram ?? if size on ram exceeds 30 MB that can cause you a problem...

Comment: It depends on the model you're targeting, but I'm pretty sure you're WAY over the RAM constraints.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore App doesn't crash till I start saving. I can add any number of Proxy images. When I start saving, then app crashes sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. Crash log of device says Low memory warning. I guess when app exceeds 30MB of memory in Allocations, it might crash. But dirty memory will not cause crash until it reaches some extent I guess. I have tested my app in very old iPod Touch as well. I can add any number of proxy images. Once I start saving, it crashes right away in iPod touch but sometimes it saves and sometimes it crashes on iPad2 and iPhone 4G.

Comment: @Dustin is there any way so that I can reduce both the sizes?

Comment: If you have a set image size and resolution, then no. If you want to reduce how much RAM gets used you probably need to save your image as a bunch of different parts and save these files one at a time.

Comment: @Dustin I am splitting the image into 16 parts before saving and finally merge into a single image while saving.

Comment: When you merge the files are they simultaneously in memory, or are you saving in a way that only one part is in memory at a time?

Comment: @Dustin Yeah only one part of memory is there at a time.

Comment: Then you probably just need to split your image into smaller pieces

Comment: @Dustin What? More than 16pieces?

Comment: If your problem is memory usage, you need to use less memory. If you're committed to a certain resolution the only way to decrease your memory footprint is to have less of the picture in memory at any point in time.

Comment: @Dustin I guess this is the only thing which is remaining for me to do now. Thanks.